# iOS: Siri does not list my iOS payments app when I ask Siri "What can you do?"

Tags: ios, iphone, swift, xcode, sirikit

I have a working Siri payments extension on an iOS app. 
But when I ask Siri "what can you do?" It does not list my app.

Siri does list Cash and Venmo payments apps (Venmo on my colleague's phone).
When you tap on the app icon Siri lists some other tutorial example sentences what can users ask Siri using their apps.

I am not able to get my app listed in Siri. Any help, please?
All the mentioned phrases in the below plist work actually with Siri.

```
My AppIntentVocabulary.plist

<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE plist PUBLIC "-//Apple//DTD PLIST 1.0//EN" "http://www.apple.com/DTDs/PropertyList-1.0.dtd">
<plist version="1.0">
<dict>
    <key>IntentPhrases</key>
    <array>
        <dict>
            <key>IntentName</key>
            <string>INSendPaymentIntent</string>
            <key>IntentExamples</key>
            <array>
                <string>iPay Steve $40</string>
                <string>Using iPay send $30 to Steve</string>
                <string>Send $50 to Steve using iPay</string>
                <string>Send $5 to Steve with iPay</string>
                <string>Send $15 to Steve for lunch using iPay</string>
            </array>
        </dict>
    </array>
</dict>
</plist>
```

[image: Siri screenshot 1]
[image: Siri Screneshot 2]
[image: Siri Screenshot 3]

Comment: Did you create an `AppIntentVocabulary.plist` file and add example sentences for your app?

Comment: I did not get it worked. I see your ans on other post. ..... "The Intent Phrases part looks mostly correct, except for one detail: your Intent Examples should include the name of your app and each intent domain has some specific keywords that need to be included in your Siri commands and hence in your Intent Examples in order for Siri to recognise them as Intents. You should test your commands in Siri and I have not worked with the INStartWorkoutIntent domain, but I am fairly sure, the keywords start and workout are necessary."

Comment: I am adding my plist in the question. Please check. I gave plist target as App. Did not work. And then I gave plist target nothing. Then too nothing. Is somethign wrong?

Comment: The target needs to be your app. Your plist file looks correct as well. Is your intent actually working with Siri, is it just not showing the examples? Or your app doesn't work with Siri at all?

Comment: 1. I set the target as my app. 2. My intent is working with Siri very well. 3. It is not listing my app in Siri Guide (Tap on question mark at the left bottom and scroll up. I see Venmo and Cash. But not my app.).

Answer (score 2):

I know this is an old question, but there isn't robust documentation about this topic.

The easy way to make work this is uploading the app to iTunes Connect, you can check the documentation from [here](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/sirikit/registering_custom_vocabulary_with_sirikit/global_vocabulary_reference).

Pay attention to:

> When you submit your app to the App Store, your
>   AppIntentVocabulary.plist file and any localized versions of that file
>   are sent to Siri for processing.

After upload the build, you have to wait some minutes/hours to see your phrases in Siri "what can you do".

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure if you have solved this issue already.
This is documentation link for [IntentPhrases](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/sirikit/registering_custom_vocabulary_with_sirikit/global_vocabulary_reference/intent_phrases)
What helped me:

1. AppIntentVocabulary.plist should be placed in the target of your app
   and not in Siri extension target.
2. Also, make sure the AppIntentVocabulary.plist is added to the Base localization. Include localized versions of your vocabulary property list file in the language-specific project (.lproj) directories of your app